# Why do we say "traffic jam"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, phrases

A thought occurred to me during a tedious journey yesterday, when travelling why do we use the word *jam* when describing being

> …caught in a *traffic jam*?

It is just a queue, in this case, it happens to be composed of traffic but if I was in a shop waiting in a queue of people I wouldn’t say I was *in a people jam* or *queue jam*... why not?

Comment: Ever used the expressions, "paper jam", the "printer is jammed" or said, "the paper is jammed in my printer"? Why do you think the term "jam" is used there? Has jam (in the US "jelly")  got a liquid or semi-solid consistency?

Comment: "I got stuck in a traffic butter" doesn't have the same ring... but "taffic mud" or "traffic sludge" could work...

Comment: @Mari-LouA I like the idea of a "traffic marmalade" or "traffic curd" though.

Comment: Understand that the two meanings of "jam" -- a verb for "wedge" and a noun for a gooey substance -- merge in the mind to produce a perfect description of a "traffic jam".

Comment: Also understand that a "traffic jam" is not simply a queue.  Rather, there is some obstruction causing the problem (though sometimes the obstruction is just a 4-way intersection where each direction is blocking passage for the other directions).

Comment: Of the early examples dredged up by Eliphind.com, this one from 1908 is by far the most fun (upper left). https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030193/1908-07-31/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22traffic%2Bjam%22. The phase appears to be preceded by log jam and ice jam, so borrowed from river flows, apparently.

Comment: and supporting that is this ngram for *traffic flow* and *traffic jam*. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=traffic+flow%2C+traffic+jam&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctraffic%20flow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraffic%20jam%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sense of jam in traffic jam meaning traffic congestion developed out of the verb connotation of obstructing, blocking or become immovable. The expression dates back to the early 20th century.

As The Word Detective explains:

> “***[Jam](http://www.word-detective.com/2011/09/jam/)***” first appeared in the early 18th century as a transitive verb meaning “to press or squeeze something” or “to wedge or immobilize something in an opening”. The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) labels it “apparently onomatopoeic”.
>
> - *(“The Ship … stuck fast, jaum’d in between two Rocks,” Defoe, Robinson Crusoe, 1719)*.
>
> “Jam” as a verb went on to mean “to block or obstruct” (eventually producing the “jamming” that can block radio signals) and, as an intransitive verb, meaning “to become immovable or unworkable by wedging or sticking” as a gun may “jam.”
>
> - ***As a noun, “jam” developed a variety of meanings, most of them involving either the act of “jamming” or the result of “jamming,” as in a “traffic jam”*** or, in a figurative sense, “jam” meaning a difficult situation (“I’m in a jam. But I’m not going to the cleaners… Half of this money is mine,” Raymond Chandler, 1950).